# SR501 PIR Motion sensor outputs high voltage in signal pin

Tags: sensor, motion, pir

I have connected a SR501 is powered by 5v converted from 12v through 7805 voltage regulator. The output voltage on the signal pin is normally 5v and on high it outputs 8v. This makes my relay module to be always on. Any idea what is happening. The main supply is 12v 2A. Any work around to over come this also will help. Connection diagram below.

[image]

Another thing that i noticed here is, the voltage between VCC and Signal is 3.3v during high signal, the voltage between vcc and signal is 8v

Comment: At a minimum we need schematics, and possibly also a picture of the actual circuit. Datasheets would help, too. Please [edit] this information into your question.

Comment: Sorry I will update this question once I am in my system. I thought it's a common component

Comment: That is not normal behaviour for an HC-SR501 PIR module. It should output 0v when not triggered and +3.3V when detecting movement. Are you sure it's supplied with 5V (and not more) and did you connect Vcc and ground properly? Please include a schematic or an image of your setup.

Comment: sounds like the 7805 is wired wrong

Comment: 7805 pin 2 has to be connected to the GND, the (-) of the power source.

Comment: i have updated my question with some additional info

Comment: You are connecting +12V to the Vcc of a 5V relay board (at least it looks like one, but please look it up in its documentation). That does not look right. Connect the Vcc of the relay board to +5V. Also, are you sure you’ve measured the output of the PIR sensor relative to its GND? Also, the 7805 needs capacitors at its input and output for stabilization.